# css sprite animation : delay between loops

Tags: css, animation, sprite

i'm trying to animate a png sprite.
My goal here is to rotate an object smothly, ie with no pause
or visual inconsistency between loops, like a well designed 'busy' gif will look like.

Why not go with a gif? Because i want more colors in my images,
and i'm currently trying to learn about the new css3 stuff too.

So, i came up with this stylesheet:

```
.hexagon
{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background:url('http://i59.servimg.com/u/f59/18/89/55/67/hexago10.png');    
    -webkit-animation: playhexagon .5s steps(18) infinite;
    animation: playhexagon .5s steps(18) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes playhexagon {
   0% { background-position: 0px; }
   100% { background-position: -4500px; }
}

@keyframes playhexagon {
   0% { background-position: 0px; }
   100% { background-position: -4500px; }
}
```

I use 18 steps because there is 18 images in the sprite, and `infinite`, obviously, for the infinite animation.

As you can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sk9o3L3g/2/) this is not so bad, but not perfect : i don't know how to suppress the (small) delay between the loops.

if you don't see it clearly, try to change the animation duration : switching between 0.5 and 1s made it somehow more obvious for me.

I think it's because the animation start and end positions in the sprite are in fact the same image (0px and -4500px render the same image in the sprite)

I saw that the `0% { background-position: 0px; }` instruction is optional, the animation play exactly the same way without it, but i wrote it to explicitely state what is going on.

I tried some tricks with no results to resolve this:

- show only one time the first image in the sprite betwwen loops, or
- double the speed of the end and start animation so this will go unnoticed for the eye

I would prefer using only css, but if it's not possible i will go full javascript. So long for the new css3 animation stuff.

Thanks for any insight and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's not the browser/css/animation that's pausing. It's simply the way that particular animation is made, with two very similar frames that make it *feel* like it's pausing.

To demonstrate, you can change the animation to start halfway through and finish halfway through. If it were pausing, you would now expect the pause to be when the hexagon is horizontal instead of facing you, but actually it looks exactly the same.

```
@keyframes playhexagon {
   0% { background-position: 2250px; }
   100% { background-position: -2250px; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sk9o3L3g/4/

Comment: well the sprite is composed of 18 different images, So i will lose one if go with 17. I tried it already, but i will check your fiddle nonetheless

Comment: there is 18 different images in the sprite (you can check it), but the instruction 0px and -4500px show the same image in the sprite (the first one) sry if i'm not clear

Comment: i made more tests with an updated png with 17 images(minus the last one of the previous png), and i still see a very small pause between the loops, but it may be just a feeling

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is just a feeling - try the change I suggested above and see if the pause appears to happen at a different point in the sequence. If it doesn't, it means the pause is purely down to the images. Also, try doubling the sprite size - see if it only pauses every second iteration. If it pauses in the middle, again it's down to the images. Finally, try it with something less subjective - e.g. a circle divided into arcs. I'm pretty confident you'll find I'm right. This is a pretty common usecase and it works very well in a lot of similar animations.

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/sk9o3L3g/6/ (using an image from http://spiffygif.com/docs/#png-sprites)